# prevent direct download of zip, tar files through URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, download

I have a PHP app whose directory has some zip, tar files. I recently noticed that they are available for download directly through the URL. How can i stop that? I think, maybe through `.htaccess`.

My `.htaccess` as of now is like this:

```
Options All -Indexes
IndexIgnore *
IndexIgnore *.jpg *.gif *.xls *.jpeg *.png *.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php
```

Comment: move them out of DocumentRoot

Comment: well, i know that. But, what i am asking is how to stop it when its inside the documentroot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent access to specific files, 
you can use the directive `<Files>` in your .htaccess

```
<Files ~ "\.zip$">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

Since Apache 1.3, recommandation is to use `<FilesMatch>` instead, which allows the filenames to be matched against regular expresssions

For example, the following code will block access to files ending in .ini, .log, .sh and .zip

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ini|log|sh|zip)$">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to modify permissions to that files? i think that modifying permissions to 600 or something might work

Comment: thanks. Stupid me, why didn't i think of it before? it works all good. One more question, what should be the permissions for `.htaccess` file, right now its 644. Is it fine?

Comment: Yes, normally this is the permissions for htacess because need to be written. I'm glad it worked :)

Comment: No, htaccess is not supposed to be written once set.

Comment: Moreover I think the choice of configuration depends on who is creating the zip files : www-data on the php server or an other user or application?

Comment: @PhilSummers: Yes, you're right, i forgot the "no". It's a file that it's no need to be written

Answer (score 1):

maybe it's too late but you also can use this method

```
RewriteRule .*\.(zip|jpg|php|gif|js)$ - [F,NC]
```